# VMware - How to allow IP/Ports access

Tags: vmware

I red lot of post about this question without find the good answer. The situation is simple, I have a server (Go) running on Ubuntu 14.04 (VMware Workstation 12.1.0 Pro). It listens on the 8001/8002 ports. From the host of the VM (Windows 10), I can access it from the host (Windows 10) but from my Xamarin Application or the others computers, I can't access this server.

I tried lot of things such as port transfer, edit of the NAT propreties (of the VM) and edit of the vmnetnnat.conf file as well. I tested about bridge connection but I didn't find the way to make it works with this way. etc

I also did transfer port from my internet box to get the access by IP instead of private network address (192.168.XXX.XXX) but it didn't works too.

If anyone can help, thank !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default your Workstation configures your VM in either NAT or Host-only or event in Custom network configuration what means your host computer (you Windows 10) is the only endpoint which can access this box without any additional configuration in your router.

I would suggest you the easiest way is to use "Bridge" configuration what you mentioned below by getting (perhaps DCHP) IP schema from your parent router (the one gives your Windows 10). Thus your VM will be available across your "Home network", Once done, check your ICMP (pings) from Windows 10 to your VM, make sure you can see it.

Second point is that your 8001/8002 ports might be closed by firewall (iptables) in your ubuntu / Windows 10. You probably want to check your both firewalls as your traffic is being routes by "Virtual router" of Workstation.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I take a look at this once I get back to my house ! I'll send you a message after and valide your answer :)